# How to create a GridView from a class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm new to asp.net and have recently been working with creating a GridView from codebehind to make it more flexible so that I can eventually have it created based on user specifications.

Now I'm exploring classes, and I thought it would be cool to create a GridView class so that whenever I need to make a GridView I can just pass the class my specifications instead of having the same code re-written on each page's codebehind.

I'm not really seeing too many examples of how to accomplish this though.  Have any of you done this?  Does it even make sense for me to do this?

Here's how I'm currently making my GridView with codebehind.  Any idea how I can change this to create the GridView with a class?

.aspx page:

```
<asp:GridView  ID="GridView1"  runat="server"  AllowSorting="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
 EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." AllowPaging="True" 
 CssClass="GridViewStyle" GridLines="None" Width="100%">
    <Columns>                       
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="EmployeeID"
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="EmployeeProfile.aspx?EmployeeID={0}"
            DataTextField="EmployeeID"
            DataTextFormatString= "<img src='Images/icons/document-search-result.png' alt='View'/> <u>View</u>" >
            <ControlStyle CssClass="titleLinksB" />
            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
        </asp:HyperLinkField>                          
    </Columns>
    <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
    <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyRowStyle" />
    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="5" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" />
    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
    <EditRowStyle CssClass="EditRowStyle" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRowStyle" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortasc"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortdesc"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>        
</asp:GridView>
```

.aspx.vb Code-behind page:

```
Partial Class GridTest2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Sub Page_load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        CreateGridColumns()
        BindGrid()
    End If
End Sub

Public Property SortExpression As String
    Get
        If ViewState("SortExpression") Is Nothing Then
            ViewState("SortExpression") = "LastName ASC"
        End If
        Return ViewState("SortExpression").ToString
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        ViewState("SortExpression") = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub CreateGridColumns()
    Dim curLastName As New BoundField
    curLastName.HeaderText = "Last Name"
    curLastName.DataField = "LastName"
    curLastName.SortExpression = "LastName"

    GridView1.Columns.Insert(0, curLastName)


    Dim curFirstName As New BoundField
    curFirstName.HeaderText = "First Name"
    curFirstName.DataField = "FirstName"
    curFirstName.SortExpression = "FirstName"

    GridView1.Columns.Insert(1, curFirstName)

End Sub

Private Sub BindGrid()
    Try
        Dim tblData = New DataTable
        Using sqlCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConnectionString").ConnectionString.ToString())
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Employees"
            Dim sqlCmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
            sqlCmd.CommandText = String.Format(sql, Me.SortExpression)
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon
            Using objAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
                objAdapter.Fill(tblData)
            End Using
        End Using
        GridView1.DataSource = tblData
        GridView1.DataBind()
        GridView1.HeaderRow.CssClass = "HeaderStyle"

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' TODO: log error '
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanging
    Me.GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    BindGrid()
End Sub
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    'Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    Dim gridView As GridView = DirectCast(sender, GridView)
    Dim sortColumn As String, sortDirection As String
    sortColumn = Me.SortExpression.Split(" "c)(0)
    sortDirection = Me.SortExpression.Split(" "c)(1)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
        Dim cellIndex As Integer = -1
        For Each field As DataControlField In gridView.Columns
            If field.SortExpression = sortColumn Then
                cellIndex = gridView.Columns.IndexOf(field)
            End If
        Next

        If cellIndex > -1 Then
            '  this is a header row, set the sort style
            e.Row.Cells(cellIndex).CssClass = If(sortDirection = "ASC", "sortasc", "sortdesc")
        End If
    End If

End Sub




Private Sub GridView1_Sorting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles GridView1.Sorting
    Dim currentSortColumn, currentSortDirection As String
    currentSortColumn = Me.SortExpression.Split(" "c)(0)
    currentSortDirection = Me.SortExpression.Split(" "c)(1)
    If e.SortExpression.Equals(currentSortColumn) Then
        ' switch sort direction '
        Select Case currentSortDirection.ToUpper
            Case "ASC"
                Me.SortExpression = currentSortColumn & " DESC"
            Case "DESC"
                Me.SortExpression = currentSortColumn & " ASC"
        End Select
    Else
        Me.SortExpression = e.SortExpression & " ASC"
    End If
    BindGrid()

End Sub


End Class
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you are trying to make Custom Gridview class. you can follow below links for your help. All you need to do is make a class which inherits Gridview class so that you override default functionality to make it more generic.

[Extending the GridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163612.aspx)

[Custom Gridview with paging and filtering](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/gridview/Custom-GridView-with-Paging-and-Filtering.aspx)

[Creating Custom Gridview Control](http://aspalliance.com/1768_Creating_Custom_GridView_Control)

Comment: This info should help.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually I'm still a little confused here.  What I'd like to do is create an external class that I can use so that when I want to create a GridView on any page I can use that class instead of manually creating it in each page's code-behind.  The code I provided works to make a GridView from code-behind. I'm just trying to figure out how to rewrite it so it can be created from a class instead.

Comment: To be quite honest with you i have personally asked this question on MSDN a year ago and MSFT guy said that it is a very BIG job. Extension of Gridview is not easy. what i provided is a good start but from there you are alone my friend.:) Good Luck